# How to execute more than one command on one line?

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

I am new to Linux, and I am having an issue of not being able to fully execute these lines of code. I have researched for hours and have also spent plenty of time manipulating these myself and still cannot create something that looks how it should be. Thank you all ahead of time.

*How it is supposed to look:*

```
$. network.sh
Today is: Day, Month, Day (numerical), year
The hostname for localhost.localdomain is: 192.168.xxx.xxx
```

Here is how it *currently* looks.

```
 . network.sh
 Today is: Sunday, October 11, 2015
 The hostname for localhost.localdomain
 is: [kris@localhost Desktop]$
```

`is` is on the next line. This completely disregards my last line of command and does not display it on the same line as "the hostname for localhost.localdomain".

Current file...

```
#!/bin/bash
# Script to print the current date
echo -n "Today is: "
d=$(date +%A," "%B" "%d," "%Y)
echo "$d"
# Show IP in color
echo -n "The hostname for " ; hostname ; echo -n "is:" ; echo -n ip addr list eth1 |grep "inet " |cut -d' ' -f6|cut -d/ -f1
```

Comment: Look at http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x264.html

Answer (score 2):

Just interpolate the sub processes outputs:

```
echo "The hostname for $(hostname) is: $(ip addr list eth1 |grep "inet " |cut -d' ' -f6|cut -d/ -f1)"
```

The nested `"` are fine (the $(subshell) parsing takes precedence)

Comment: Thank you so much! I have also added `tput setaf 1` after 'Is:' to make the IP address turn red.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
echo "The hostname for $(hostname) is: $(ip addr list eth1 | grep "inet " | cut -d' ' -f6 | cut -d/ -f1)"
```

Or, I suggest:

```
ip=$(ip addr list eth1 | grep "inet " | cut -d' ' -f6 | cut -d/ -f1)
echo "The hostname for $(hostname) is: $ip"
```

Comment: Nice idea to show the use of a variable to get more readable code